# Calling elasticsearch serach method from javascript (client side) using elasticsearch.js with a helper method queryBuilder?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

The user will enter search string  and some filters based on which the query builder will build a different query body. Then I try to pass it to the elasticsearch search method as specified in the elasticsearch.js api . When i hardcode the query in the search body it works fine. But when I try to call my queryBuilder funtion or store it in a variable and try to put it in the search body it doesnt work (queryBuilder is working properly as i have printed it out ).

I am new to javaScript, any help will be appreciated. I have attached a picture of working code  and picture of codes not working and the error . Thanks alot . 
working
[image]
NotWorking
[image]

Comment: don't add pictures of codes add codes instead of pictures

Comment: +1, it would be easier to help with code provided. But nevertheless I'd try to stick to JSON notation strictly: `query: { queryBuilder() }` ain't help. JSON as dictionary should always have `key` and `value`. JSON as array might be just number of JSON dictionaries. So I think you should rather try smth like (with appropriate amendments): `body: { query: queryBuilder() }`. For more information please use samples like these: http://www.saintsatplay.com/blog/2015/09/generating-json-objects-dynamically-in-javascript.